Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(VideoError, Failed to load video: Operation Stopped, null, null)
Im using video_player: ^2.9.0. On Android it's working fine, but i get an error on iOS device.

Video Player Error: Failed to load video: Operation Stopped
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(VideoError, Failed to load video: Operation Stopped, null, null)

How i can manage what i have to do for this error?
I want to play to video from URL for both Android and iOS device. I have searched for the solution but none of them work. Some date before that was working but now its not working. this problem is related to video URL or from the flutter..?

did you try play video with the https url? i see this in github issue since 2020 until now it's still open issue.

yes dear i'm using the https only...
